How to bake lean turkey?
I am new to cooking,
I have lean turkey meat 125 grams each.
i want to cover it in butter with spices. Would you advise me to cover it in butter or olive oil?
how long and at what temperature should i bake it?
Thanks.

Hi, for the oil or butter part - it's up to taste, use whichever you like more. For the time, see the linked question, it explains it very thoroughly.
